# How can I pass parameters to a local page in PhoneGap app?

Tags: ios, cordova, parameters

In a PhoneGap app, we can setup the starting page using the following code.

```
self.viewController.wwwFolderName = @"www";
self.viewController.startPage = @"index.html";
```

But it won't work if I want to pass parameters to that page.

```
self.viewController.startPage = @"index.html?parameter=abc";
```

It will cause an `NSURLErrorRedirectToNonExistentLocation` error.

Is there an easy way to pass parameters to a local page?

Comment: Since it's local, why don't just put the parameter in your javascript?

Comment: @wmfairuz  There are cases that parameters are not determined at compile time.

Answer (score 6):

In phonegap apps, you cannot call local pages by passing parameters to them because the system searches for files with exactly the same name as you pass. It doesn't treat the parameters as query string.

```
Ex: when you say "index.html?param=abc", instead of calling page index.html with a
parameter called param having value abc. It calls the page "index.html?param=abc"
which doesn't exist in the system. Hence, the error.
```

The best method to solve the issue is to save your parameters as local storages in the calling page, consume them in your next page and destroy them.

```
Ex: In your calling JavaScript file, use:
window.localStorage.setItem('param', 'abc');

Now, in your called file, access the local storage and delete it
param abc = window.localStorage.getItem('param');

window.localStorage.removeItem('param');
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Actually you can, at least using jQuery mobile

Answer (score 1):

Edit: for Cordova & Phonegap apps this plugin is useful http://goo.gl/TWN8wq so you do not have to do all by yourself manually modifying the Android manifest or the iOS plist files. 
There is also the advantage of being able to use the same `handleOpenURL()` function on both platform (you cannot without the plugin, `handleOpenURL()` would be a iOS thing only)

Anyway, manually:

To achieve what you want, you have to :

1 - Register a custom scheme (like HelloWorld) and custom url (like `customurl`) in xCode

2 - Place a link on the page like`<a href=”HelloWorld://customurl/username=James Bond”>HelloWorld</a>`

3 - Get the value of the parameter `username` using the function `handleOpenURL` for Phonegap < 3.0 or `OpenURL` for Phonegap 3+, like:

```
function handleOpenURL(url) {

                    //Here we can parse the url .

                    var link = url.split(‘=’);

                    var username = link[1];

                    alert(username);

}
```

There is a full tutorial on how to do it [here](http://mindfiremobile.wordpress.com/2013/10/03/handling-phonegap-ios-application-using-custom-url-scheme/) (iOS) which is where I took everything from.

Credits to Sourabha Kumar Sahoo

Comment: What I wanted to do is just passing parameters to a local html file.

Comment: Why the down vote? @WeiLiu you ask how to pass parameters to `index.html` as you wrote `index.html?parameter=abc`. Anyway, that is the only way to go. On your index.html page, just save your parameters in LocalStorage or whatever and use them on the page you need. Phonegap apps always load index.html as entry point, then you have to go from there in your js code.

Comment: I don't have a link to tap and start my app.

Comment: Well then how can the parameters you want to pass to the starting page be dynamic?

Comment: You mean the only way to make parameters dynamic is to use a link?! Use your head, pls.

Comment: Nice attitude, congrats. I am using my head and my time trying to help you, which is the main purpose of this site. Sorry for bothering you, you will not hear from me ever again.

Answer (score 0):

If I was you, I would just pass all of the information to javascript via a plugin method that you will create(i.e. plugin.GetQueryString() ) You can create a general plugin method that will return all of the query parameters as a string, and then you can process it in javascript with a following method:

```
function getQueryParams(qs) {
    var params = {},
    tokens,
    re = /[?&]?([^=]+)=([^&]*)/g;

    while (tokens = re.exec(qs)) {
        params[decodeURIComponent(tokens[1])]
        = decodeURIComponent(tokens[2]);
    }

    return params;
}

window.$_GET = getQueryParams(plugin.GetQueryString());
```

As a result you will get a nice data structure with all of your GET parameters that you can access by name.