# Watch for edits programmatically in Google Spreadsheet Database

Tags: javascript, html, database, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using Google Spreadsheets as a JSON database (I know, not totally reliable or the best option). I was wondering If I could somehow "watch" this database for edits, or if I could send a trigger from the database to a web application upon edits of the content?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Apps Scripts. Which is a scripting language based on JavaScript that lets you do add functionalities to Google Sheets and other Google products.

You can go in **Tools -> Script Editor** in your spreadsheet. There you can create functions triggered on editing the sheet.

Example of a Google Apps Script function:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
var values = rows.getValues();

for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
  var row = values[i];
  Logger.log(row);
}
```

You may need to use [URL Fetch Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/) to make a request on your application whenever a row or cell is changed.

Comment: Thanks, I have been using Google Apps Scripts to add data to the spreadsheets, but I didn't know about URL Fetch Service. I will check it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Manual edits?  For manual edits, create an `onEdit()` function.

[Google Documentation - Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/index)

If the spreadsheet is getting data written to it through a Google Apps Script that is NOT under your control, then you could have a time driven trigger that is checking the spreadsheet at regular intervals.

[Time Driven Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers)

Comment: Great I can use the Time driven triggers to get the changed data; however, I am still confused on how to send this data (from Google Apps Scripts) to my application.

Comment: Websites typically use search string parameters in the URL to send info to an HTML application, or to control navigation and deep linking.  What is your application?  A website?

Comment: No, it is a PhoneGap application. Would I be able to send search string parameters in the url, or is there another way of doing it. Thanks

Comment: I don't know about PhoneGap, maybe search some questions like this one:  [StackOverflow Pass Parameters to PhoneGap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15781540/how-can-i-pass-parameters-to-a-local-page-in-phonegap-app)