# Simple cordova app for passing information from one page to another using typescript

Tags: typescript, apache-cordova

I've created an Apache Cordova app(TypeScript). But I don't know how to pass the information from one html page to another html page using typescript.
Please let me know what steps I need to follow for navigation and for posting data to another page.
Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pass parameters to a local page in PhoneGap app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15781540/how-can-i-pass-parameters-to-a-local-page-in-phonegap-app)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`localStorage`](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_storage_localstorage_localstorage.md.html) to set parameters from one page and get them from another.

Comment: thanks, But I also want to know how to navigate from one page to another with typescript using winjs or somthing other